# Fill ICollection<Class> with proper parent objects

Tags: c#, algorithm, icollection

I have a class:

```
public class MyObject {
    int id;
    int parentId;
    MyObject parentObj;
}
```

and I need to fill parentObj with proper objects. I need to do this with look on performance and simplicity.

So I have code:

```
ICollection<MyObject> Method(ICollection<MyObject> coll)
{
    foreach(var item in coll)
        ...

    return coll;
}
```

that I would need to fill the parentObj with proper objects from this collection. As I can think the complex of this problem is N*log(N).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classic approach is using dictionaries. The lookup operation (retrieve the value for a given key) can be implemented in *O(1)*. This assumes a good hash function that maps the key to a position in a lookup array.

Using the default `Dictionary` implementation in .net, this will result in this code.

```
ICollection<MyObject> Method(ICollection<MyObject> coll)
{
    var lookup = new Dictionary<int, MyObject>();
    foreach (var item in coll)
    {
         lookup.Add(item.id, item);
    }
    foreach (var item in coll)
    {
         item.parentObj = lookup[item.parentId];
    }

    return coll;
}
```

There is a memory overhead with allocating `lookup`, but the runtime will be (theoretically) *O(n + n) = O(n)*

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Comment: The first 4 lines can be simplified using Linq extension method `ToDictionary`.